# Application for playing media from a server

Tags: java, animation, media-player, media, fullscreen

I would like to write an application that will connect to an ftp server to fetch animated media (flash animations, powerpoints, mainly videos). Then display these documents in loop in fullscreen.
I would like some suggestions. Can it be done with a JAVA application?

Answer (score 0):

Java Media Framework (JMF)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html